# i need to display customer’s first name and last name who have made the most number of booking. Using select

Tags: sql, select

> So using this table i have to display customers F Name and L name, so
> I tried using (Group By) but didn't work

```
>     CREATE TABLE bookingxx (`enter code here`   BookingLastname varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,   BookingFirstname varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
> BookingNumber varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,   BookingState varchar(20)
> DEFAULT NULL,   BookingDate date DEFAULT NULL,   FlightNumber
> varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,   SeatsBooked int DEFAULT NULL,  
> TotalCharges int DEFAULT NULL,   BookingTotal int DEFAULT NULL );
> 
> 
> INSERT INTO bookingxx (BookingFirstname,BookingLastname,BookingNumber,
> BookingState, BookingDate, FlightNumber, SeatsBooked, TotalCharges,
> BookingTotal) VALUES ('James','Bond','BK01', 'Perak', '2021-06-12',
> 'FLT6', 200, 6000000, 200), ('John','Weak','BK02', 'Negeri Sembilan',
> '2021-06-16', 'FLT7', 140, 1400000, 140), ('John','Tina','BK03',
> 'Pahang', '2021-06-15', 'FLT3', 300, 8000000, 300),
> ('Uno','Tabalo','BK04', 'Sabah', '2021-06-13', 'FLT6', 100, 1000000,
> 100), ('Zratus','Kratus','BK05', 'Sarawak', '2021-06-01', 'FLT5', 240,
> 4400000, 240), ('Mohd','Ali','BK06', 'Perak', '2021-06-10', 'FLT6',
> 330, 3800000, 330), ('Hussam','Saleh','BK07', 'Wilayah Persekutuan ',
> '2021-06-17', 'FLT8', 190, 1900000, 190), ('Hamza','Hazem','BK08',
> 'Pahang', '2021-06-03', 'FLT3', 80, 800000, 80), ('Ali','Anas','BK09',
> 'Sarawak', '2021-06-01', 'FLT5', 90, 100000, 90),
> ('Abdull','Jabar','BK10', 'Negeri Sembilan', '2021-06-02', 'FLT7',
> 300, 5000000, 400);
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Looking at your sample data you have all unique names and unique booking numbers, so this would be a very simple `where` clause. You have not explained the relevance of all the columns in your data; exactly what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem i am trying to solve is. I Want to display the first name and last name of the customer who has the most booking amongst the rest of the customers using the (Select) Operator

Comment: Each person has exactly 1 booking, giving the `BookingNumber` column. You have a `BookingTotal` column but you make no reference to this, your question needs clarity.

Comment: BookingNumber is the Unique id of the booking. And the BookingTotal is the Total number of booking's made by costumers. So all i want is to Select the first name and last name of the customer who made the most bookings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need the name of the person with the highest value `Bookingtotal`.

You don't specify your RDBMS, however

```
select top(1) BookingLastName, BookingFirstName
from bookingxx
order by BookingTotal desc
```

Your specific database might use `limit` instead of `top`; you can also use `with ties` for where the same total is shared by more than one.